# Printing key when value is found in hash table

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to print the key value(s) in a hash table when the value is found or exists. This code does not seem to work.

```
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(int j=0;j<al.size();j++){            
        Integer count = map.get(al.get(j));       
        map.put(al.get(j), count==null?1:count+1);   //auto boxing and count

    }
    int max = Collections.max(map.values());
    if( map.containsValue(max))
    {

     System.out.println(map.keySet());
    }
```

Comment: If the hashmap contains the max value, its corresponding key should be printed. Very new to hashtables and Maps. Help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it printing all the keys instead of the one you want?

Comment: yes, it is printing all the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the values could occur *multiple* times - I assume you want to print *all* matching keys?

Secondly, hashtables basically aren't designed for lookup by value - so you have to iterate all the entries:

```
// Adjust types accordingly
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals(targetValue)) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

You should change the equality check if it's possible that some of the values are null.

Comment: Hi, yes. I am trying to print all matching types. How does Map.entry work again? I am very new to java and hashtables.

Comment: @user872009: the `Map.Entry` type is "an entry in the hashtable" - a single key/value pair. The `entrySet()` method returns a set of entries you can iterate over.